# Windows Auth with Http.Sys on Windows 10 IoT Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, windows-authentication, windows-10-iot-core

I make an asp.net core windows auth application with HttpSys server and the dev machine works without any problem but when I upload it to Windows 10 IoT Core we get the following problem:

```
failHosting environment: Production
Content root path: C:\Data\Users\Administrator\Documents\publish
: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.HttpSys.HttpSysListener[0]
      GetContextAsync
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.HttpSys.HttpSysException (998): Invalid access to memory location
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.HttpSys.HttpSysListener.AcceptAsync()
Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.HttpSys.MessagePump[0]
      ListenForNextRequestAsync
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.HttpSys.HttpSysException (998): Invalid access to memory location
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.HttpSys.HttpSysListener.AcceptAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.HttpSys.MessagePump.ProcessRequestsWorker()
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.HttpSys.HttpSysListener[0]
      GetContextAsync
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.HttpSys.HttpSysException (998): Invalid access to memory location
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.HttpSys.HttpSysListener.AcceptAsync()
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.HttpSys.MessagePump[0]
      ListenForNextRequestAsync
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.HttpSys.HttpSysException (998): Invalid access to memory location
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.HttpSys.HttpSysListener.AcceptAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.HttpSys.MessagePump.ProcessRequestsWorker()
```

And my Auth Settings are:

```
WebHost
    .CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .UseStartup<Startup>()
    .UseHttpSys(options =>
    {
        options.Authentication.Schemes = AuthenticationSchemes.NTLM | AuthenticationSchemes.Negotiate;
        options.Authentication.AllowAnonymous = false;
    })
    .Build();
```

and

```
services.AddAuthentication(HttpSysDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
```

Comment: Which build of Windows IoT Core did you run the asp.net core application on? I have created an asp.net core project and published it for win-arm, when i run the app, i got the exception as `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.HttpSys.HttpSysException (50): The request is not supported`. My Windows IoT Core is 17763.107.

Comment: Have you restarted the device and then run the app?

Comment: Yes, Windows 10 IoT don't support Http.Sys!